# Select text of element containing a div with specific class

Tags: html, css, scrapy

I am using scrapy css selector to extract the below html and load it to an item loader.

How do I extract the text of `td`, in which this `td` contains a `div` with class `sweetness`

i.e. I want to extract the text `Dry`.

*HTML code:*

```html
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="grape">
        </div>
        Cabernet Sauvignon
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="sweetness">
        </div>
        Dry
    </td>
</tr>
```

In the scrapy `ItemLoader`,I have defined a field `sweetness`, but I am not sure what is the css select query for this.

*PYTHON code:*

```py
def parse_wine(self, response):
    wine_item = response.meta['wine_item']
    loader = ItemLoader(item=wine_item, response=response)
    ...
    loader.add_css('sweetness', '????')
    yield loader.load_item()
```

Answer (score 0):

See below -

```
loader = ItemLoader(item=wine_item, response=response)
loader.add_xpath('div_content', '//td/div[@class="sweetness"]')
loader.load_item()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled long time on this problem and realized that css doesn't support selecting parent node [parent selector in css](https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/).

Fortunately xpath selector is much more powerful than css selector! It's supported by lxml package in scrapy, where xpath is actually the first-class, and a superset of css, whereas css is only an extension to it (actually a separate package and all [css selectors are translated to xpath](https://lxml.de/cssselect.html)).

So coming back to your question, just use parent path to go from your `div.sweetness` to parent node `td`

```
...
loader.add_xpath('sweetness', '//div[@id="answer-13134778"]/parent::*')
...
```

or a shorthand

`````
....
loader.add_xpath('sweetness', '//div[@id="answer-13134778"]/..')
````
`````

should do it!